# Многопоточность в JAVA EE

Tags: java-ee, многопоточность, java

Насколько часто используется многопоточность в Web проектах? 
Если да, то хочется какой-нибудь пример, что можно например в сервлете делать в двух потоках, особенно в высоконагруженном проекте,где еще один поток созданный сервлете это N потоков от кажого пользователя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервлет во многих веб контейнерах (практически во всех) уже сам находится в многопоточной среде, так что пытаться делать его многопоточным бессмысленно - это задача контейнера.